# Razor form - upload and attach to email

Tags: razor, umbraco

I am implementing a razor contact form on Umbraco CMS, which includes inline C# script to create and send an email using .Net's MailMessage.  The end user now needs to be able to upload a file, which gets added to the email as an attachment.

From my knowledge, the only way to do this is by uploading to the disk and then loading the attachment from the disk.

Is it possible to upload and attach without writing to disk?  Keep in mind there is no code-behind or controller - this is all in-line razor logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `InputStream` from the uploaded file to the MailMessage's `Attachment` constructor:

```
if(IsPost && Request.Files.Count > 0){
    var file = Request.Files[0];
    var fileName = file.FileName;
    var attachment = new Attachment(file.InputStream, fileName);       
    ...
    ...
```

Make sure that (unless you are using the FileUpload Helper) you set the form's method to `POST`, add an `enctype` attribute with a value of `multipart/form-data`, and that you provide your `input type=file` with a `name` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to look at Request.Files, but it's giving me a count of zero.

Comment: Without more info, it's difficult to diagnose why that might be. Double-check the things I said the make sure of.

Comment: I had a problem with nesting forms.  Once I cheated the form tags, your code example worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much is possible with razor, but it should be possible to upload and attach to an email without saving to disk. Use the Stream you get from the [FileUpload.FileContent property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent.aspx) of the upload control. Then pass that to [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sdktyws.aspx) of the MailMessage Attachement.

Also, why not use code-behind?

Comment: No code-behind because I'm using a CMS content system with a downloaded razor all-in-one contact form.  I'm avoiding re-inventing the wheel.